# Extjs(version 5.0.0.970) is running slow in New chrome update version 53.0.2785.101

Tags: extjs

I have updated my google chrome ,but Extjs performance is significantly reduced.I dont know exactly why.Can anyone share reason to this.
Note: New version is 53.0.2785.101

Comment: what version of ExtJS might help..

Comment: I am using version 5.0.0.970.But I dont think so its specific to this Extjs version only.

Comment: Same thing on ExtJS 4.2, so yes - not version specific. Also same thing on Opera 40 which has the same JS engine.

Comment: Added a bug report for Blink (Chrome, Opera): https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=650651

Answer (score 0):

I gone through same problem last week. Chrome 52 version had some major bugs that was reason ExtJs application had some Performance issue. They have fixed some major bugs in v53.
    If you have major issues with ExtJS then you should check it's Heap size and analyze it's memory consumption using chrome dev tool. It might help you to find out bottleneck of your application.

Comment: can you please tell me in detail, related to heap size and all.

Comment: When you open console then first go with timeline and then find out memory leakage or repaint issue. This timeline will guide you what to do next. Then you can go with Heap ScreenShot and you can navigate through all objects and references of it.

There might be reason that, if Garbage Collector is running multiple times in couple of seconds then it might affect main thread of browser. When Garbage collector runs then all execution of JavaScript stops till GC get stop. So get to know when your GC is running.